How to get SE sstatic images for my website
I've written about 2,500 questions and answers in Stack Exchange sites. About half of them I scrape into my website on GitHub Pages for customized presentation and searching.
A short time ago all the images disappeared because of SE's switch from imgur server to sstatic server. I've read on other posts that my website likely wouldn't be put on the "allow list".
I will have to programmatically change links. For example, consider this grep output:

2024/2024-04-28-Data-Explorer-Query-crashes-with-collation-conflict-error.md:47:  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/195OOXx3.png

The Github Pages markdown would change to:
[1]: https://www.pippim.com/assets/img/_posts/2024/195OOXx3.png

Changing the Kramdown (markdown) is the easy part. The hard part is downloading all the images. Consider the number of images:
$ grep sstatic _posts/*/* | wc -l
480

480 manual downloads is too tedious. The website is refreshed weekly (after SE's Sunday data dump) with a simple bash command and any new images would also need to be manually downloaded.
The only method I can think of is passing a list of sstatic URLs to a python script which uses selenium to open Chromium to open Google Search to open the link to use image save as and then close the image tab.
From then on, only image URLs for new posts since the last refresh need to be downloaded with the python script. Selenium is OK but it uses a lot of CPU resources and programming is awkward.
Is there an easier way to download a list of images from sstatic.net?

If you're already using Python, chances are requests.get should suffice - there's no need to bother with Selenium or a headless browser.

@iBugsaysReinstateMonica I'll give that a try before Selenium. However from my IP address I can't access sstatic.net. I can only do it via Google Search which is on SE's "allow list".

Wget worked fine for me just now. For example:
wget https://i.sstatic.net/93s1DAKN.png

wget accepts a list of URLs.
It surprised me that such a simple command worked. I'd expected I'd need to pass my fkey in form data or something, and maybe fake origin and referrer headers, but apparently not. And you don't need to scrape for non-deleted post contents. Just use SEDE.

wget works like a charm and is very fast. The image in my question only took 0.06 of a second to download 196,840 bytes. Also I'm already using a SEDE query to download..

Website is up and running fine now. Thanks for your help!

If the image ID has 5 chars, then it's likely in my Stack Exchange Image Dump (to download all images: ia download stack-exchange-images --retries==100).

While useful, downloading the whole dump seems like an overkill just for ~500 images.

@ShadowWizard OP tagged their question with [data-dump] so I gave them a dump :)
